# Spring boot. Beans initialisation using instance variable

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to initialise beans using instance variables. So I have base class which contains the information to create a queue given a queueName and messageListener.

The beans are not getting initialised. Can someone please look into my code and help. My aim to create classes which other classes can use to reduce code duplicity. That is why I am using instance variable to create beans.

```
//class Application

package com.ats.myntra;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
    }
}








//class RabbitMqQueue

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

import org.springframework.amqp.core.MessageListener;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.Queue;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class RabbitMqQueue {
    private String queue;
    private MessageListener messageListener;

    public RabbitMqQueue(String queue, MessageListener messageListener){
        this.queue = queue;
        this.messageListener = messageListener;
    }

    @Bean
    MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter() {
        return new MessageListenerAdapter(messageListener, "onMessage");
    }

    @PostConstruct
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
        container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        container.setQueueNames(queue);
        container.setMessageListener(messageListener);
        return container;
    }

    @Bean
    Queue queue() {
        return new Queue(queue, false);
    }

}





//class q1
package Configuration;


import org.springframework.amqp.core.Message;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.MessageListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class q1 implements MessageListener{

    q1 q = new q1();
    String queue = "abcd";


    RabbitMqQueue rabbitMqQueue = new RabbitMqQueue(queue,q);


    static void print(){
        System.out.println("why");
    }

    //rabbitMqQueue = 
    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }   
}
```

Comment: I want to make this RabbitMqQueue class reusable by any queue. So if I am required to add a queue in future, I don't need to change this class.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your configuration class. Don't use constructor injection for those values, and instead just inject directly on the fields. I modified your example with the assumption that you have a property named "queue.name" in your configuration files, but you can change this to whatever you are using.

```
@Configuration
public class RabbitMqQueue {

    @Value("${queue.name}")
    private String queue;

    @Autowired
    private MessageListener messageListener;

    @Bean
    MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter() {
        return new MessageListenerAdapter(messageListener, "onMessage");
    }

    @PostConstruct
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
        container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        container.setQueueNames(queue);
        container.setMessageListener(messageListener);
        return container;
    }

    @Bean
    Queue queue() {
        return new Queue(queue, false);
    }

}
```

Or instead, you can actually just inject the values into the bean factory methods like this:

```
//snip
    @Bean
    @Autowired
    MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter(private MessageListener messageListener) {
        return new MessageListenerAdapter(messageListener, "onMessage");
    }
//snip
    @Bean
    Queue queue(@Value("${queue.name}" String queueName){

        return new Queue(queue, false);
    }       
//snip
```

Hope that helps:)

Comment: I don't want to autowire messageListener. Otherwise my RabbitMqQueue won't remain reusable by other queues.

Comment: I'm not so familiar with RabbitMq, so I'll have to take your word on that. Still (for my own learning sake), why would it not be reusable? It also appears that you already have it being created as a bean since it's annotated with "@Componant", so I don't see how injecting it would cause any problems. If it isn't thread safe, then it should not be a bean. The only other way I can think of is to create a factory class and method for retrieving the value, or creating a new instance of the listener inside the factory method "listenerAdapter" that only the adapter uses..

Comment: See if I am injecting it, I am essentially making a change in RabbitMqQueue.java class. I want to somehow inject it using constructor like we do in Strategy design pattern.

Comment: Maybe we have a different understanding of the strategy design pattern? The point of the strategy pattern is to make decisions at runtime based on the state of the application. Container injection is one way of accomplishing that. If you add the value into the constructor like you are doing, this prevents that object reference from being changed or modified at runtime. Your "RabbitMqQueue" class is a configuration class, so it should never be referenced  nor created by anything other than the container (Spring). If you want reusability, then you must use injection.